# How to update record which is duplicated PL/SQL in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates

I have table called sales_staff_08 and firstname, surname, username as 3 cols.

username is concatenated by using firstname and surname.

because it might be duplicated. Therefore I want to avoid by adding some number.

Current table

```
USERNAME   
---------- 
JOHSMITH1 
TOMNGUYE1
STEREDMO1
BOBJOHN1
CARJONES1
DANCREIG1
STEREDMO1
TOMNGUYE1
```

I want to update RECORD that is duplicated, it should be shown like this:

```
USERNAME   
---------- 
JOHSMITH1
TOMNGUYE1
STEREDMO1
BOBJOHN1
CARJONES1
DANCREIG1
STEREDMO2
TOMNGUYE2
```

My first attempt to update records

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_concate_names IS 

 vc_username VARCHAR(25);
 v_number NUMBER (2) := 1;

 CURSOR cur_concate_username IS 
 SELECT firstname, surname, username FROM sales_staff_08; 

 BEGIN

    FOR rec_cur_concate IN cur_concate_username 

    LOOP

    vc_username := rec_cur_concate.firstname || rec_cur_concate.surname || v_number;

    UPDATE sales_staff_08 ss
    SET username = vc_username
    WHERE ss.username = rec_cur_concate.username;

 END LOOP; 

 END proc_concate_names;
 /
```

Comment: I think you've to change your table structure, mainly to add unique id for each name, in order to update the username with where condition using the respective id, instead of rec_cur_concate.username,.

Or i think there is a possible way using trigger.

Comment: Actually I had sales_staff_id as primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with one command:

```
merge into sales_staff_08 d
using (select firstname ||surname || row_number() 
           over (partition by username order by firstname) un, rowid 
       from sales_staff_08 ) s
on (d.rowid = s.rowid)
when matched then update set d.username = s.un;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/466cc/1)

As @Plouf stated this can also be done as an update command:

```
update sales_staff_08 d
set d.username = (
  select un from (
    select firstname ||surname || row_number() 
            over (partition by firstname, surname order by firstname) un 
     from sales_staff_08
  ) s
  where s.rowid = d.rowid
)
```

[Here is another sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/466cc/3)

Comment: @Plouf, that's because I don't know how to do it in a **simple** update, only a very **not simple** update, and IMHO a merge is nicer since the query stays clean. Anyway, since you challenged, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Plouf, acctually there is - the inner view of the `update` needs to be calculated for each `d.rowid` since I used a `window function` (row_number()), but in the `merge` I would excpect it to find the rsultset once and join it to the result of d

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. What is s ? My table actually has sales_staff_id and should I replace it as rowid?

Comment: @TommyNguyenDuc, if it's a unique key than you can (should) replace, what doesn't work - what do you get instead of the correct results ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade: Thank you for your kindness. I made it work :) by taking last 2 digits of sales_staff_id :)

Answer (score 2):

A.B.Cade answer is more reliable. First, merge and update will work faster if there are millions of rows. Because in first case, you are using both plsql engine and sql engine for operation. It means in each loop of plsql engine, it will call sql engine. In second case it will use full independent sql engine which is faster.